# Surf.Create not found

Tags: c#, opencv

When I execute in OpenCvSharp3:

```
SURF detector = SURF.Create(400);
```

I got exception error:

> Unable to find an entry point named 'xfeatures2d_SURF_create' in DLL 'OpenCvSharpExtern'.

Thanks,

King

Comment: I think OpenCV web page implies it is a none free algorithm

Answer (score 0):

With the move to OpenCv 3.0 SIFT and SURF were moved to opencv_contrib.  At the moment OpenCvSharp3 does not support the opencv_contrib module.

See this link for an alternative approach
https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/146

And this link that shows a way to enable the contrib code in OpenCvSharp3. This approach is tricky but do-able.
https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp/issues/180